# I am not sure why this is showing an error

Tags: java, greenfoot

I am not sure why this is showing an error on greenfoot.It says this is an incompatible type. How to fix it , as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eq8y5.jpg)

Comment: Please add the code you are having issues with to the question as text.

Answer (score 0):

In last version of Greenfoot there is a special class **Color**. It interferes with *awt* class Color with the same name. Use the Greenfoot's class **Color** in your code. For example:

```
    public MyWorld()
    {    
        super(600, 400, 1); 
        GreenfootImage bgr = getBackground();
        int r = (int)(0.8f * 255);
        int g = (int)(0.95f * 255);
        int b = (int)(1.0f * 255);
        int a = (int)(1.0f * 255);
        Color bgrColor = new Color(r, g, b, a);
        bgr.setColor(bgrColor);
        bgr.fill();
    }
```